# Create a list with EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am currently learning EasyMock and I have read some tutorials about it. Based on the knowledge, I have acquired, I try to create a mock list but it gives me AssertionError, whose reason I could not understand.

Basically, I want to have a list, whose first element is 1133L and second element is 1139L and the size of it is naturally 2.

My method

```
@Test
public void testCreateIdealConf()
{

List< Long > idList = createMock( List.class );

expect( idList.get( 0 ) ).andReturn( 1133L );
expect( idList.get( 1 ) ).andReturn( 1139L );
expect( idList.size() ).andReturn( 2 );

replay( idList );

for( int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++ )
{
  System.out.println( "Elements: " + idList.get( i ) );
}
}
```

When I run this test method, it gives the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Unexpected method call List.size():
List.get(1): expected: 1, actual: 0
List.size(): expected: 1, actual: 2
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.size(Unknown Source)
at de.psi.passage3.auslieferung.allg.gui.status.CasBarUserConfigurationArrangementsTest.testCreateIdealConf(CasBarUserConfigurationArrangementsTest.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 
the rest of the failure trace is omitted.
```

Where do I make a mistake or do I except something wrong from a mock object/list?

Comment: I've not used easymock, but it looks like you are telling it to expect `get(0), get(1), size()`, but the actual method calls would be: `size(), get(0), size(), get(1), size()`.

Comment: @khelwood Now, based on your answer, I have tested and you are right. The order also matters :) If you change your comment as answer, it will be accepted as solution.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help.

Comment: Please note: i assume this is only for understanding how EasyMock works ... because in reality, you would not need to do such things. You know, you use a mocking framework for things that you really need to control. Lists ... you really do not need to control. What I mean is: if you have "code under test" that deals with a certain list, then just create an ordinary list, and give that to your class under test. And then you verify that your code does the expected things, given the provided input. You really shouldnt verify what **your** code is doing with that list object you passed to it!

Comment: @Jägermeister You are right. It is easier to create an ordinary list and then pass this list to the method. However, as a newbie on this framework, I just wanted to use all the possibilities, the framework provides:) Under normal conditions, i will mind what you have written here. Thank you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are telling it to expect:

```
get(0)
get(1)
size()
```

but the actual method calls would be:

```
size()
get(0)
size()
get(1)
size()
```

Answer (score 2):

use anyTimes() method to disable checking of the call order and call executions.

```
expect(idList.get(0)).andReturn(1133L).anyTimes();
expect(idList.get(1)).andReturn(1139L).anyTimes();
expect(idList.size()).andReturn(2).anyTimes();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that by default, checking the call order and call executions is disabled, as long as createMock instead of createStrictMock is used.

Answer (score 1):

You are not expecting the `.size()` call in the for loop, try:

```
int listSize = 2 ;
expect(idList.size()).andReturn(listSize).times(listSize+1);
expect(idList.get(0)).andReturn(1133L);
expect(idList.get(1)).andReturn(1139L);
```